# Default model used in stlm() function in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, ets

When forecasting of a seasonal time series is done using stlm() or stlf() in R and no model is specified, what is the default model used?
Ps- I read the documentation and searched on the internet but couldn't find any lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help file:

> `stlm` takes a time series `y`, applies an STL decomposition, and models the seasonally adjusted data using the model passed as `modelfunction` or specified using `method`. It returns an object that includes the original STL decomposition and a time series model fitted to the seasonally adjusted data. This object can be passed to the forecast.stlm for forecasting.

If you look at the default arguments, `modelfunction=NULL` and `method="ets"`. So it uses an ETS model on the seasonally-adjusted data.

Answer (score -1):

IN NOT SPECIFIED ANY METHOD OR Model name, like below codes, what method is used here for forecasting a time series decomposed by mstl method in R:
,,,,
stlm_model <-msts_train %>%
stlm(lambda = 0) %>%
forecast(h=48)
plot(stlm_model,xlim) = c(230,240))